# How to read VarBinary Data from the SqlServer ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, binary

I have a binary data (Object of MyClass) in SqlServer field, But i am not able to retrieve the binary value and convert it into My Class Object.
I have used following code to write into the DB.

```
        conn = getConnection();
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStream);
        sw.Write(sql);
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO PExercise(P_Enroll_No,P_Exercises,P_Date) VALUES (@VarEnroll,@VarBinary,@Date)", conn);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@VarEnroll",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,Int32.MaxValue);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@VarEnroll"].Value = sql.getEnrollNo();
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@VarBinary", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@VarBinary"].Value = memStream.GetBuffer();
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Date",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,Int32.MaxValue);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = date;

        int success = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        closeConnection();
```

This code successfully writes my data into the table. I have used following code to read it from database.
please help me with the code.

```
            conn = getConnection();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select P_Exercises from PExercise where P_Enroll_No='" + enrollNo + "' AND P_Date='"+date+"'", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            long i = dr.GetBytes(0,0,bytes,0,1024*1024*8);


            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            ms.Position = 0;
            mc = (List<ExerciseDetails>)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

I have searched a lot but still have no luck.
Above code is giving me Exception "Invalid Read, No Data is Present".
I have also tried QueryManager to run the sql query. and its working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following where you do an ExecuteScaler as safe cast it as a byte array. By the way, make sure you wrap objects that implement IDisposable with using statements so they are closed and disposed properly.

```
   using (var cn = _db.CreateConnection())
   using (var cm = cn.CreateTextCommand(sql))
   {
       cm.AddInParam("name", DbType.String, name);
       cn.Open();
       var data = cm.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];
       return data;
    }
```